# Google TV SDK send params from remote control mobile app to GoogleTV app

Tags: google-tv

is possible to send parameters to my Google TV app from the mobile remote control app ( http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/ ) to open my Google TV application and take these parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The Google TV Remote app implements the Anymote protocol which has a fling message to send intents (with extra data) to a Google TV device: https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/#flingevents